# Poll TCP socket idle listen

Tags: c++, sockets, ubuntu

I am sorry if the title is misleading. I cannot really think of a better one. Here is some simple socket program that I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <iostream>

#define BACKLOG 10

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }


     int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");


     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     int portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

     auto bindsuccess = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

     if (bindsuccess < 0)
        error("ERROR on binding");

     struct pollfd newPollFD[1];
     newPollFD[0].fd = sockfd;
     newPollFD[0].events = POLLIN;

     char buffer[256];
     bzero(buffer,256);

     listen(sockfd, BACKLOG);

     struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
     socklen_t clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

     int newsockfd;

     int rv = poll(newPollFD, 1, -1);

     if (rv == -1) {
        error("Error occured in Poll");
     }
     else {
        if (newPollFD[0].revents & POLLIN){

            newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
            if (newsockfd < 0) 
                error("ERROR on accept");

            int rwsuccess;

            rwsuccess = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
            if (rwsuccess < 0)
                error("ERROR reading from socket");

            printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);

            rwsuccess = write(newsockfd,"I got your message \n",18);

            if (rwsuccess < 0)
                error("ERROR writing to socket");
        }
     }

     close(newsockfd);
     close(sockfd);
     return 0; 
}
```

If I execute this code with a port number, and then telnet to that port number, the server listens in, but as soon as I send my first message, the connection terminates. I want the sever to keep on listening and sending acknowledgement back as many times as I send message from telnet. How do I accomplish that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and I'm not sure how the code compiles as given with that `continue` statement and no loop.

Comment: That was a dumb mistake on my part. I was trying something before posting it. Forgot to remove it. Sincere apologies.

Comment: It sounds like you were on the right track, because `continue` requires a loop, and a loop is what you want.

Comment: @Subhamoy Sengupta, Could I ask why you poll(..) right after listen(...) and before accept()? I thought accept() is a blocking call. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>The `continue` is curiously extraneous, and causes the compilation to break.</s> (It is now corrected in your edit.) But, you are missing a `for` loop. And, you should add a check if the `read` returns `0`.

```
        for (;;) {
          int rwsuccess;

          rwsuccess = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
          if (rwsuccess < 0)
              error("ERROR reading from socket");
          if (rwsuccess == 0) break;

          printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);

          rwsuccess = write(newsockfd,"I got your message \n",18);

          if (rwsuccess < 0)
              error("ERROR writing to socket");
        }
```

Comment: I don't think the continue affects compilation, but it may have some run-time issues.  It does seem extraneous though.  Yeah, a loop is needed in order to continue reading from the socket.  Otherwise that code just closes the socket after one read and write.

Comment: @gonzobrains: I got `error: continue statement not within a loop`. Regards

Comment: Thank you! I guess it was not a very smart question to ask :P

Comment: @user315052 Yeah, you're right.  I assumed his code compiled for some reason because he said his code just closes the socket.  Perhaps it's compiler dependent, but yes, continue belongs in a loop!